# Как сделать настройки для первого запуска?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как поставить настройки для игры? В самой игре человек сам сможет поставить определённые настройки (сенса и т.п.). Но при первом запуске запуске уже должны были быть выставленны первоночальные настройки. Мб их в в каком то файле выставить, или в настройках проекта?
Настройки я сохраняю через PlayerPrfbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("example")) PlayerPrefs.SetInt("example",1);
```

читается

> если настройка "example" не имеет значения - задаем "example" значение 1